# Java: Unexpected behaviour with concatenating a String and an expression using the plus + operator

Tags: java, string, operator-keyword, behavior

Consider the following piece of code

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String... strings) {
      System.out.println("String, " + false);
      System.out.println("String, " + getFalse());
      System.out.println("String, " + new TestClass());
      System.out.println("String, " + (new TestClass() == null));
      System.out.println("String, " + new TestClass() == null);
   }

   private static class TestClass {
      public String toString() {
         return "false";
      }
   }

   private static boolean getFalse() {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Why does the last `System.out.println` print a different output than the others? I have no idea, is this a bug? Is it to do with the plus operator? The StringBuilder?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: It's a legitimate question, see comments below code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"String, " + new TestClass() == null`

would be considered as

`("String, " + new TestClass()) == null`

therefore prints out `false`

(you can check out more details in the [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html))

Comment: @user3649372 Glad it help, you can click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrow. I think you have done it before :p